# Disable focus of jquery ui radio button while displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When i use jquery ui radio buttons automatically the first radio button is getting focused.
How can i disable it[image]

Comment: Which one you want to focus either?

Comment: @user3168736 none. because it's begining of showing the buttons.

Comment: So you want no pre selection. right>

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqVGu/141/) Do you want this? Check this fiddle and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div input:radio').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is may not be the best... But. it is working.

```
<input autofocus style="display:none;"/>

<div id="Ref_opt">
   <label for="Ref_opt1">Label</label>
   <input type="radio" id="Ref_opt1" name="Ref_opt" value="1">
   <label for="Ref_opt2">Label 2</label>
   <input type="radio" id="Ref_opt2" name="Ref_opt" value="2">
</div>

<script>
    $( "#Ref_opt" ).buttonset();
</script>
```